# Can't search a value in a simple json array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a json column in my table that looks like this :

```
+-------------------------------+
| referrals                     | 
+-------------------------------+
| [123,456,789]                 | 
+-------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to filter through that array to find out if a value from another tables ID  match. So, imagine, I have a column named payID and I want to know if payID matches with any values of that json array. And after that I just select the usernames of those matched payID's.

```
(select group_concat(u.name) from
 ns_accounts a inner join ns_users u on u.id = a.uID
 where a.payID in (123,456,789)) as payID,
```

If I search for that payID in a static list like above, it works perfectly and I get the usernames just fine. However, when I try to search for it dynamically like so :

```
(select group_concat(u.name) from
 ns_accounts a inner join ns_users u on u.id = a.uID
 where a.payID in
 (replace(replace(replace(json_unquote(referral), '', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''))) as payID,
```

I just get null. That's where I get confused, because

```
(replace(replace(replace(json_unquote(referral), '', ''), '[', ''), ']', '')))
```

The output of this is the same as if I typed the values by hand, just like above, so it would give me : 123,456,789. I'm confused why it would work if I typed in statically and not dynamically. My only guess would be that the output of that expression is a string and that's why it keeps giving me null, but I'm not sure. I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you store referrals in a normalised way befitting a relational database? It would make your life a lot easier! Btw, the dynamic search does not work, because `123,456,789` is not the same as  `'123,456,789'`

Comment: I certainly hate working with jsons, but I couldn't find another way, I have to store values in an array and since mysql doesnt support arrays, I kinda had to go with jsons lol

Comment: No, you do not have to store values as an array, you can store them as rows one-by-one in a separate table. Basic normalisation.